# PHP_ Exibir na própria página informação do HTML SELECT

Tags: php

preciso de uma ajuda em PHP... 
gostaria que assim que o usuário clicasse em uma opção do SELECT, fosse mostrado na mesma pagina, abaixo do form.

poderiam me dar uma ideia de como fazer?

EXEMPLO:

Valor 1 
  Valor 2
  Valor 3

Assim que o usuário escolher um valor aparecer na pagina HTML abaixo e se ele continuar escolhendo outros valores assim que clicar no botão continuar exibindo um debaixo do outro no HTML...

Comment: Tens um código inicial ?

Comment: Para isso você nem precisa usar PHP. Pode fazer com html e javascript/jQuery. Mas mostre o q você ja tentou fazer antes!

Comment: Vc pode fazer uma requisição JQuery, como o @alan citou não necessariamente seria necessário o PHP, a não ser que os valores a serem mostrados venham de um banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo duas opções de como fazer com jquery.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  // opção 1
  if ($(this).val()) $('div.op1').append($(this).val() + '<br>');

  // opção 2
  if ($(this).val()) $('div.op2').append($('#html'+$(this).val()).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
<hr>
<div class="op1"></div>
<hr>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="html1">Conteúdo HTML 1<br></div>
  <div id="html2">Conteúdo HTML 2<br></div>
  <div id="html3">Conteúdo HTML 3<br></div>
</div>
<div class="op2"></div>
```